# How do I run queries against a view configuration

Tags: 7, views

Where is all the config for Views stored? I am working on a Drupal site with a very large number of Views. What's the easiest way to find *"All the Views which have a Relation of a certain type"*, or *"All the Views which output a specific field?"*

It would be nice to do this with some SQL but I'm stumped as to how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's stored in the `views_display` table, as a serialised PHP string. So unfortunately direct querying isn't really feasible.

The best approach is to load each View object in turn (in PHP), and apply your filter logic there.

The [`views_ui_field_list()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21admin.inc/function/views_ui_field_list/7.x-3.x) function is a good example of what's required. Incidentally that's the callback for a page that already exists in the admin which should help you find *All the Views which output a specific field*. It's at /admin/reports/fields/views-fields.

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding a bit on @Clive's answer. Load all views, iterate through them and check what you need.

Views has a function that will help, `views_get_all_views()`, https://cgit.drupalcode.org/views/tree/views.module#n1536

From there, you can go through them and get what you need.

Basically,

`$views_list = views_get_all_views();
  foreach ($views_list  as $view) {
    //Logic operating on the $view object
  }`

This will probably be useful as well, https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/class/view/7.x-3.x